# Stop layered navigation retainining filter when moving between categories

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I am using layered navigation a custom theme (based on RWD) and the filter is keeping the value when moving between categories. Can anyone please tell me where I would start debugging this issue? Or is there anyway I can force the filter to clear when moving between categories?

Comment: Any ideas? Is there anyway I can debug this?

Comment: I have flat categories enabled and wonder if this is perhaps causing the issue?